# Plot with abline a regression line without intercept

Tags: r, regression, lm

I am implementing a linear model in R, where I use "y ~ 0+x" to fit a model
without intercept. When I use then "abline(0, 2.08193)" the line does not go through the origin - why is that and how can it be corrected?

```
x <- c(2.9, 6.7, 8.0, 3.1, 2.0, 4.1, 2.2, 8.9, 8.1, 7.9, 5.7, 1.6, 6.6, 3.0, 6.3)
y <- c(5.118289 17.168719 14.489016  7.340286  8.422882  7.994184  4.455667 17.529257 16.628453 17.076216 14.855261 2.596441 12.039215  6.684931 11.456480)

mod0 <- lm(formula = y ~ 0+x)
plot(x,y, xlab="x ", ylab="y ")

summary(mod0)
abline(0, 2.08193)
```

[image]

Comment: plot(x,y, xlab="x ", ylab="y ",xlim=c(0,max(x)),ylim=c(0,max(y))) ; abline(mod0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
x <- c(2.9, 6.7, 8.0, 3.1, 2.0, 4.1, 2.2, 8.9, 8.1, 7.9, 5.7, 1.6, 6.6, 3.0, 6.3)
y <- c(5.118289, 17.168719, 14.489016,  7.340286,  8.422882,  7.994184,  
       4.455667, 17.529257, 16.628453, 17.076216, 14.855261, 2.596441, 
       12.039215,  6.684931, 11.456480)

mod0 <- lm(formula = y ~ 0+x)
plot(x,y, xlab="x ", ylab="y ", xaxs="i", yaxs="i", xlim = c(0,10), ylim = c(0,20), )
abline(mod0)
```

[image]